# Find, diff function in c#

Tags: c#, matlab, find, diff

I have a bunch of code in Matlab script which I want to convert it in c#. More specifically my basic problem are the following:

```
X= find(diff(S>0.5) ==1); //greater than the threshold
Y= find(diff(S<0.5)==1);  // lower than the threshold
```

In fact I want to search in a real time signal when it begins to take values bigger than 0.5 (when in increasing order). How can I convert this line in c#?

My signal is look like:

[image]

I want to spot real time when my signal begin to take values greater and lower than some thresholds which are marked in the plot. In order to do so I am using diff function in order to find these points. Firstly (S >0.5) returns a vector the same size as S which contains logical values either 1 if S is bigger than 0.5 or zero in contrast. The difference of that vector return 0 if the previous value of the vector is the same 1 if the previous value is 0 and the current 1 and -1 in the contrast. Thus find in that case "==1" returns all the points where the signal is bigger than the threshold when in ascending order. I store the values of the signal real time in the list parts:

```
parts.Add(this.confidence);
```

I want to find where in this list the signal has pass through 0.25 threshold. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Give it a shot using a `for` loop and come back with code if you have problems

Comment: I am struggle finding something for diff.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JoseRamon Don't try find something for `diff`, it's conceptually extremely simple. Just implement it in a loop yourself. Remember, C# is not Matlab, loops are the idiomatic and correct way to go in C#. At the moment your code is asking for someone to recommend a tool or library which is off topic for this forum. Demonstrate that you've tried to code this yourself and ask questions about problems with actual code.

Comment: What does the line do? It's likely that a LINQ equivalent exists, but you'll need to explain your code to us C# folk first.

Comment: Find those values in a signal  S which that taking greater values than one in ascending order.

Comment: @DavidArno My point is that in Matlab you would do something like this with the intention of then applying a function to the entire returned vector (or more likely to use it as a mask). In C# finding this result may itself be a completely unnecessary step, LINQ or no. What the OP intends to do next very possibly does not require that calculation of this vector the way Matlab does so I was trying to say don't just copy the Matlab code to C# line for line (and especially don't just ask SO users to do it for you) because optimal Matlab is very different from optimal C#

Comment: @JoseRamon That is not what that line of Matlab code does at all. I suggest that you post some sample input and output data.

Comment: Yes it looks for the first value that takes value bigger than 1.

Comment: #Dan I wan just to spot in my real time signal when it began to take values greater and lower than a threshold. This is what I can achieve using the diff function inside the find in matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to search in a signal when it takes bigger values than 1 in ascending order

Let's assume your signals are `double`'s and you have some sort of collection of them:

```
var signals = new List<double> { ... };
```

Then you can create a subset of those signals, where the value is > 1 in ascending order with:

```
var filteredOrderedSignals = from signal in signals 
                             where signal > 1.0 orderby signal ascending 
                             select signal;
```

This may not be exactly what you need, but will set you on the right path.

Comment: The OP's Matlab code implies that they want the locations of elements that are larger than `1` *and* where the previous element was not (not that I'm encouraging you to write this code for the OP, just pointing out that this does not answer the question)